# Refreshing error stating Memory not enough in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, refresh

Im getting refreshing error stating that there is not enough memory to load the rows.My file size is 208 MB and i cannot figure it out why this is happening every time while refreshing.I have tried refreshing with unticking auto date/time  under option but still this error appears.Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Power BI 32-bit (click "File" and then "About" in desktop to find out), then I would suggest uninstalling and installing a 64-bit version.

Another potential fix is to head to "Data Cache Management Options", clear cache or increase the "maximum allowed" figure.

Comment: im already installed 64bit version and i cleared data cache and increased the maimum allowed too.But still this error popping up.